# Bash variable expansion and assignments

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world"
$a='~'
$b='$a/nlu'
echo $b
```

I got

```
./test.sh: line 3: =~: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: =$a/nlu: No such file or directory
```

as errors what's the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello world"
a='~'
b="$a/nlu"
echo $b
```

- Don't use `$` for assignments.
- `b='$a/nlu'` -- Expressions like `$a` don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
- As pointed out by @steeldirver `./test.sh: line 4: =$a/nlu: No such file or directory` is the result of `$b` expanding to nothing, as the assignment was not properly done, and then `bash` tries to execute `=$a/nlu` as a command. Exactly the same for `./test.sh: line 3: =~: command not found` applies.

For future errors use `shellcheck` from the eponymous package or its [online version](https://www.shellcheck.net).